# Deploy failed on online GlassFish, works locally

Tags: deployment, jsf, glassfish, ejb

I have an EJB JAR + JSF WAR that runs fine on local GlassFish deployed from NetBeans, but if i try to deploy the WAR on an online GlassFish, I get the following error:

```
Exception while loading the app : 
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! 
com.ejb.entity.myEntity
```

**EDIT** GlassFish Log Message:

**Message ID**

```
Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start... com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException
```

**Complete Message**

http://pastebin.com/deSsYgDV

Also:

- EJB deploys fine on online GF
- EJB @ local GF: sometimes yes, mostly not: http://pastebin.com/9R1acDVq
- The EJB is pretty messy, both interfaces implement the same methods: When a session bean has remote as well as local business interface, there should not be any method common to both the interfaces. Should I fix this first?

Both servers are configured the same way. The EJB is imported in the WAR. What could be the problem? Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Activate logging and check the logs for something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a session bean has remote as well as local business interface, there should not be any method common to both the interfaces.

This is a NetBeans warning which I thought would cause no problems since the web application was using Local interfaces only. After removing the Remote interfaces from the EJB, I was able to deploy the WAR on both local and online GlassFish.